# Reducir la sustitucion con " str_replace_all " en R

Tags: regex, r

como puedo lograr que el str_replace_all cuando realice la primera sustitución(coincidencia) se pare y no siga buscando mas coincidencias en el diccionario

codigo que tengo.

```
library(stringr)

x <- c("VALLE PINO CORSO","LA PAZ","PAZ")
```

diccionario malas palabras (malpal) y buenas palabras (buenapal) no puedo hacer modificaciones en el orden de estos.

```
malpal.corpus <-  c("PINO CORSO","PAZ","PINO CORZO") #  patron
buenapal.corpus <- c("VALLE PINO CORZO","LA PAZ","VALLE PINO CORZO") # reemplazo

malpal.corpus <- str_c("\\b",malpal.corpus,"\\b")

vect.corpus <- buenapal.corpus
names(vect.corpus) <- malpal.corpus


str_replace_all(x, vect.corpus)

[1] "VALLE VALLE VALLE PINO CORZO" "LA LA PAZ"                      "LA PAZ"
```

Lo que busco es esto que solo la función "str_replace_all" deje la primera coincidencia

```
[1] "VALLE PINO CORZO" "LA PAZ"                      "LA PAZ"
```

por lo menos me gustaría reducir una similitud de VALLE :

```
[1] "VALLE VALLE PINO CORZO" "LA LA PAZ"                      "LA PAZ"
```

Comment: Intenta con `str_replace` en lugar de `str_replace_all`

Comment: Viendo tu resultado esperado, pareciera que únicamente estás buscando reemplazar coincidencias exactas

Comment: Efectivamente @Mariano

Comment: Hola @Marco Izaguirre gracias por tu respuesta pero lo que busco es un poco mas complejo. En realidad la funcion " str_replace " solo cambia la primera coincidencia en un registro y pasa al siguiente registro, en cambio " str_replace_all " remplaza todas las coincidencias en un registro y pasa al siguiente registro, lo que busco es que se consigan las posibles coincidencias en un registro por lo tanto se utilizaría " str_replace_all " en caso de realizarlo con expresiones regulares

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En base al ejemplo que aportas, creo que el problema, tal como te lo comentó @Mariano es más de búsqueda exacta que de uso de expresiones regulares. Una forma de resolverlo sería la siguiente:

```
malpal.corpus <-  c("PINO CORSO","PAZ","PINO CORZO") #  patron
buenapal.corpus <- c("VALLE PINO CORZO","LA PAZ","VALLE PINO CORZO") # reemplazo
casos <- c("VALLE PINO CORSO","LA PAZ","PAZ")

replace.items <- sapply(seq_along(casos), function(x) buenapal.corpus[match(casos[x],malpal.corpus)])
ifelse(is.na(replace.items), casos, replace.items)
```

El resultado:

```
[1] "VALLE PINO CORSO" "LA PAZ"           "LA PAZ"
```

Como puedes ver, logramos reemplazar `"PAZ"` por `"LA PAZ"`, no así `"VALLE PINO CORSO"`, pero esto se resuelve simplemente agregando el nuevo caso:

```
malpal.corpus <-  c("VALLE PINO CORSO","PINO CORSO","PAZ","PINO CORZO") #  patron
buenapal.corpus <- c("VALLE PINO CORZO","VALLE PINO CORZO","LA PAZ","VALLE PINO CORZO") # reemplazo
```

La lógica es relativamente sencilla, con [`sapply`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html) aplicamos sobre cada cadena de `casos`, un [`match()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html) para ver si coincide con alguna de las palabras erróneas y en caso que así fuera, recuperamos la palabra correcta que le corresponde: `buenapal.corpus[match(casos[x],malpal.corpus)]`. Al final en `replace.items` tendremos un vector de la misma cantidad de `casos` con las palabras a reemplazar o `NA` en caso de no coincidencia, por lo que, lo único que resta es hacer el reemplazo: `ifelse(is.na(replace.items), casos, replace.items)`.

Comment: Creo que esto es lo que estaba buscando gracias @Patricio Moracho e investigare mas sobre las funciones de sapply

Answer (score 3):

Si realmente necesitas las expresiones regulares, puedes escribirlas de forma tal que minimicen los conflictos que tienes, por ejemplo:

```
library(stringr)
malpal.corpus <-  c("\\bVALLE PINO CORSO\\b|\\bPINO CORSO\\b","\\bLA PAZ\\b|\\bPAZ\\b") #  patron
buenapal.corpus <- c("VALLE PINO CORZO", "LA PAZ")
vect.corpus <- buenapal.corpus
names(vect.corpus) <- malpal.corpus

x <- c("VALLE PINO CORSO","LA PAZ","PAZ", "PINO CORSO")
str_replace_all(x, vect.corpus)
```

Salida:

```
[1] "VALLE PINO CORZO" "LA PAZ"           "LA PAZ"           "VALLE PINO CORZO"
```

Si te fijas por ejemplo el caso de `"\\bVALLE PINO CORSO\\b|\\bPINO CORSO\\b"` usamos el `|` u `OR`, cualquiera de los dos casos, el primero que ocurra "matcheara" con `"VALLE PINO CORZO"`, con lo cual con `"VALLE PINO CORSO"` aplicará el primer patrón `\\bVALLE PINO CORSO\\b` y no generará problemas.

Comment: Estaba esperando tu respuesta!! Había intentado de la forma que pide el autor y no le encontré la vuelta

Comment: @Mariano, por el lado de las expresiones regulares tengo un manejo bastante elemental, con decirte que estuve a punto de ofrecerle al OP una función para evaluar todos los patrones por cada palabra y elegir el primero hasta que me acorde de `|`..

Comment: justamente pensé que me iba a salir de esa forma, evaluando uno por uno y frenando en la primera sustitución. Pensé que con las funciones de r lo iba a sacar de una forma "elegante", sin un loop, pero mi manejo elemental está justamente ahí, en el lenguaje :-) Pero viendo tu respuesta, es excelente, y fácilmente de escalar para unir los términos con `|` cuando tengan el mismo reemplazo.

Comment: No es necesario realizar lo con expresiones regulares, pero seria una respuesta muy útil en algún otro caso